# How to change SAS address on Expander

Tags: sas, lsi, address

I have the following setup - two supermicro backplane attached to one controller LSI SAS 9207-4i4e and unfortunately cannot access the disks, during boot there are disks only in one backplane, the disks from the second are missing, but when I boot some OS (livecd,pxe boot, etc) disks are not usable. When I disconnect one of the backplane (expander) everything is ok, the disks from the other expander are ok and usable. I search the net and it appeared that probably the two expanders in the backplanes have identical Expander SAS Address and I must change one of them with this tool ExpanderXtools_Lite_1.5, but on Linux there are double free buffer errors, I installed Windows 7 32bit on the first disk, it did not discover the HBA Card (and the expander).  When I boot in the Win PE 7 and install the lsi driver (then without reboot) I run the tool ExpanderXtools and it finds the HBA and the Expander, but it hangs on `Reading firmware information 500605B0000272BF` and the menu WWM where I can change the SAS Address is not active. I am running out of options and I tried with disks, without disks and nothing worked....Some who have used this tool and to tell me which windows/linux works?

Comment: Because: **Supermicro**.

Comment: Is there any chance you can obtain another backplane? That sounds terrible.